# Python function that returns True or False if the inputted matrix is a magic square without using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have two functions, one which is below:

```
def is_square(m):
for i in range(len(m)):
     if len(m[i]) != len(m):
          return False
return True
```

This one returns True if m is a square matrix, otherwise, it returns False. The problem is not with this one, it's with the 2nd function.

The second function:

def magic(m):

```
 if(not(is_square(m))): 
      return False

 # Here's where code starts.
```

This is what I attempted. EDIT: My second attempt after the feedback.

```
square = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    square.append([])
for j in range(len(m)):
    square[i].append(0)

total = 0
for i in range(len(m)-1):
    total += square[i][i]
if total != x*(x*x+1)/2:
    return False
else:
    return True

total = 0;
for i in range(x):
    total += square[i][x-1-i]
if total != x*(x*x+1)/2:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Here are the expected outcomes of this function:

```
# this should print True

m0=[[2,7, 6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8]]
print(magic(m0))

# this should print True

m1 = [[16,3,2,13], [5,10,11,8],[9,6,7,12], [4,15,14,1]]
print(magic(m1))

# this should print False.

m2 = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]
print(magic(m2))

#this should print False. 

m3 =  [[1,1],[1,1]]
print(magic(m3))

#this should print False. 

m3 =  [[1,1],[1,1],[1,2]]
print(magic(m3))
```

By the way, I'm having a hard time installing numpy, so if there's other ways without import numpy, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of errors in your original code. Mostly relating to the for loops, and ensuring that they start and stop in the right places (controlled by indentation in python).

Also you are testing for exact equality of numbers, which in the example is probably safe as you're dealing with integers, but can be an issue as numbers cannot be represented exactly as floating points.

As an example typing `1.1*3 == 3.3` returns `False` in python.

I have replaced your equality tests with `math.isclose()` tests from `math` module (I think this is only available in python 3, but not sure).

I have also added tests to check that the rows and columns all add-up as required:

```
import math

def is_square(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if len(m[i]) != len(m):
            return False
    return True


def magic(m):
    if(not(is_square(m))): 
        return False

    total = 0
    x = len(m)
    for i in range(x):
        total += m[i][i]

    if not(math.isclose(total, x*(x*x+1)/2)):
        return False

    total = 0
    for i in range(x):
        total += m[i][x-1-i]

    if not(math.isclose(total, x*(x*x+1)/2)):
        return False

    # Check rows all add-up
    for i in range(x):
        total = 0
        for j in range(x):
            total += m[i][j]
        if not(math.isclose(total, x*(x*x+1)/2)):
            return False

    # Check cols all add-up
    for i in range(x):
        total = 0
        for j in range(x):
            total += m[j][i]
        if not(math.isclose(total, x*(x*x+1)/2)):
            return False

    return True


# this should print True
m0=[[2,7,6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8]]
print(magic(m0))

# this should print True
m1 = [[16,3,2,13], [5,10,11,8],[9,6,7,12], [4,15,14,1]]
print(magic(m1))

# this should print False.
m2 = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]
print(magic(m2))

#this should print False. 
m3 =  [[1,1],[1,1]]
print(magic(m3))

#this should print False. 
m4 =  [[1,1],[1,1],[1,2]]
print(magic(m4))
```

Returns:

```
True
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: However, I can't import numpy: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/lab8-students/magic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: What you say regarding number inequality is just wrong for python. Your example compares integer division (1/10=0!!!) to a float. Try 1/10.0. The error bound in float comparison is machine precision here, and is usually safe for these simple problems.

Comment: Also, I just noticed the example contains only integers, which is always safe.

Comment: My bad! I have edited my answer to include an example where machine precision is actually an issue; although as you've rightly pointed out the examples include integers only.